# Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 4 sets of values: `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4` and one set `x`. The y values are of different ranges, and I need to plot them as separate curves with separate sets of values on the y-axis.

To put it simple, I need 3 y-axes with different values (scales) for plotting on the same figure.

Any help appreciated, or tips on where to look.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a great chance to introduce you to the [File Exchange.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)   Though the organization of late has suffered from some very unfortunately interface design choices, it is still a great resource for pre-packaged solutions to common problems.  Though many here have given you the gory details of how to achieve this (@prm!), I had a similar need a few years ago and found that [addaxis](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9016-addaxis) worked very well.  (It was a [File Exchange pick of the week](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/) at one point!)  It has inspired [later, probably better mods](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24875-addaxes-m-v1-1-sep-2009).  Here is some example output:

[image: addaxis example]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/9016/1/addaxis_screenshot.jpg))</sub>

I just searched for "plotyy" at [File Exchange.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)

Though understanding what's going on in important, sometimes you just need to get things done, not do them yourself.  Matlab Central is great for that.

Comment: Is there anything similar for x-axis?

Comment: I do not like any of the solutions on file exchange (that I could find). They do not allow you to put all Y axis on one side or the other. I find that the alternating sides is quite ugly to look at. The only one that allows all to one side has a complicated implementation for beginning users.

Answer (score 14):

One possibility you can try is to create 3 axes stacked one on top of the other with the `'Color'` properties of the top two set to `'none'` so that all the plots are visible. You would have to adjust the axes width, position, and x-axis limits so that the 3 y axes are side-by-side instead of on top of one another. You would also want to remove the x-axis tick marks and labels from 2 of the axes since they will lie on top of one another.

Here's a general implementation that computes the proper positions for the axes and offsets for the x-axis limits to keep the plots lined up properly:

```
%# Some sample data:
x = 0:20;
N = numel(x);
y1 = rand(1,N);
y2 = 5.*rand(1,N)+5;
y3 = 50.*rand(1,N)-50;

%# Some initial computations:
axesPosition = [110 40 200 200];  %# Axes position, in pixels
yWidth = 30;                      %# y axes spacing, in pixels
xLimit = [min(x) max(x)];         %# Range of x values
xOffset = -yWidth*diff(xLimit)/axesPosition(3);

%# Create the figure and axes:
figure('Units','pixels','Position',[200 200 330 260]);
h1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',axesPosition,...
          'Color','w','XColor','k','YColor','r',...
          'XLim',xLimit,'YLim',[0 1],'NextPlot','add');
h2 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',axesPosition+yWidth.*[-1 0 1 0],...
          'Color','none','XColor','k','YColor','m',...
          'XLim',xLimit+[xOffset 0],'YLim',[0 10],...
          'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[],'NextPlot','add');
h3 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',axesPosition+yWidth.*[-2 0 2 0],...
          'Color','none','XColor','k','YColor','b',...
          'XLim',xLimit+[2*xOffset 0],'YLim',[-50 50],...
          'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[],'NextPlot','add');
xlabel(h1,'time');
ylabel(h3,'values');

%# Plot the data:
plot(h1,x,y1,'r');
plot(h2,x,y2,'m');
plot(h3,x,y3,'b');
```

and here's the resulting figure:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I know of [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) that allows you to have two y-axes, but no "plotyyy"!

Perhaps you can normalize the y values to have the same scale (min/max normalization, zscore standardization, etc..), then you can just easily plot them using normal `plot, hold` sequence.

Here's an example:

```
%# random data
x=1:20;
y = [randn(20,1)*1 + 0 , randn(20,1)*5 + 10 , randn(20,1)*0.3 + 50];

%# plotyy
plotyy(x,y(:,1), x,y(:,3))

%# orginial
figure
subplot(221), plot(x,y(:,1), x,y(:,2), x,y(:,3))
title('original'), legend({'y1' 'y2' 'y3'})

%# normalize: (y-min)/(max-min) ==> [0,1]
yy = bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@minus,y,min(y)), 1./range(y));
subplot(222), plot(x,yy(:,1), x,yy(:,2), x,yy(:,3))
title('minmax')

%# standarize: (y - mean) / std ==> N(0,1)
yy = zscore(y);
subplot(223), plot(x,yy(:,1), x,yy(:,2), x,yy(:,3))
title('zscore')

%# softmax normalization with logistic sigmoid ==> [0,1]
yy = 1 ./ ( 1 + exp( -zscore(y) ) );
subplot(224), plot(x,yy(:,1), x,yy(:,2), x,yy(:,3))
title('softmax')
```

[image: plotyy]
[image: normalization]

Comment: It's been a while, but there is actually a "plotyyy"!  It's apparently been on File Exchange since 2001: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1017-plotyyy

Answer (score 5):

Multi-scale plots are rare to find beyond two axes... Luckily in Matlab it is possible, but you have to fully overlap axes and play with tickmarks so as not to hide info.

Below is a nice working sample. I hope this is what you are looking for (although colors could be much nicer)!

```
close all
clear all 

display('Generating data');

x = 0:10;
y1 = rand(1,11);
y2 = 10.*rand(1,11);
y3 = 100.*rand(1,11);
y4 = 100.*rand(1,11);

display('Plotting');

figure;
ax1 = gca;
get(ax1,'Position')
set(ax1,'XColor','k',...
    'YColor','b',...
    'YLim',[0,1],...
    'YTick',[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]);
line(x, y1, 'Color', 'b', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Marker', '.', 'Parent', ax1)

ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','bottom',...
           'YAxisLocation','left',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor','k',...
           'YColor','r',...
           'YLim',[0,10],...
           'YTick',[1, 3, 5, 7, 9],...
           'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[]);
line(x, y2, 'Color', 'r', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Marker', '.', 'Parent', ax2)

ax3 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','bottom',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor','k',...
           'YColor','g',...
           'YLim',[0,100],...
           'YTick',[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],...
           'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[]);
line(x, y3, 'Color', 'g', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Marker', '.', 'Parent', ax3)

ax4 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','bottom',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor','k',...
           'YColor','c',...
           'YLim',[0,100],...
           'YTick',[10, 30, 50, 70, 90],...
           'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[]);
line(x, y4, 'Color', 'c', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Marker', '.', 'Parent', ax4)
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [pablorodriguez.info](http://www.pablorodriguez.info/wp-content/Multiaxes.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[PLOTYY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) allows two different y-axes.  Or you might look into [LayerPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11178) from the File Exchange.  I guess I should ask if you've considered using [HOLD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) or just rescaling the data and using regular old plot?

**OLD**, not what the OP was looking for:
[SUBPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) allows you to break a figure window into multiple axes.  Then if you want to have only one x-axis showing, or some other customization, you can manipulate each axis independently.

Comment: No. That's not it. I need them on a single figure, on a single graph.

Comment: oh it seems we had the same idea of plotyy and scaling!

Comment: @Amro - kind of, my idea of scaling was going to be something along the lines of divide all the vectors by their max.  Your example is quite sophisticated!

Answer (score 0):

In your case there are 3 extra y axis (4 in total) and the best code that could be used to achieve what you want and deal with other cases is illustrated above:

```
clear
clc

x = linspace(0,1,10);
N = numel(x);
y = rand(1,N);
y_extra_1 = 5.*rand(1,N)+5;
y_extra_2 = 50.*rand(1,N)+20;
Y = [y;y_extra_1;y_extra_2];

xLimit = [min(x) max(x)];
xWidth = xLimit(2)-xLimit(1);
numberOfExtraPlots = 2;
a = 0.05;
N_ = numberOfExtraPlots+1;

for i=1:N_
    L=1-(numberOfExtraPlots*a)-0.2;
    axesPosition = [(0.1+(numberOfExtraPlots*a)) 0.1 L 0.8];
    if(i==1)
        color = [rand(1),rand(1),rand(1)];
        figure('Units','pixels','Position',[200 200 1200 600])
        axes('Units','normalized','Position',axesPosition,...
            'Color','w','XColor','k','YColor',color,...
            'XLim',xLimit,'YLim',[min(Y(i,:)) max(Y(i,:))],...
            'NextPlot','add');
        plot(x,Y(i,:),'Color',color);
        xlabel('Time (s)');

        ylab = strcat('Values of dataset 0',num2str(i));
        ylabel(ylab)

        numberOfExtraPlots = numberOfExtraPlots - 1;
    else
        color = [rand(1),rand(1),rand(1)];
        axes('Units','normalized','Position',axesPosition,...
            'Color','none','XColor','k','YColor',color,...
            'XLim',xLimit,'YLim',[min(Y(i,:)) max(Y(i,:))],...
            'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[],'NextPlot','add');
        V = (xWidth*a*(i-1))/L;
        b=xLimit+[V 0];
        x_=linspace(b(1),b(2),10);
        plot(x_,Y(i,:),'Color',color);
        ylab = strcat('Values of dataset 0',num2str(i));
        ylabel(ylab)

        numberOfExtraPlots = numberOfExtraPlots - 1;
    end
end
```

[The code above will produce something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrQcl.png)