# Which multi-axes, multi-scale plotting tool to use?

Tags: plot, time-series

I am looking for plotting tools capable of using more than one or two vertical axes with different scales, like for instance:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/9016/1/addaxis_screenshot.jpg))</sub>

The goal is to plot several time series with different ranges in a same plot. For instance, I could have:

- Time series 1 with range [-1, 1]
- Time series 2 with range [-10, +10]
- Time series 3 with range [0, 1500]
- Time series 4 with range [0.5, 0.9]

Ideally I could plot each time series in its own axis with its own range, as shown in the image.

Which tools or libraries do you know that can do this?

Note: this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes), but I'm looking for more possibilities than Matlab.

Comment: I knew about matlab (addaxis), matplotlib and ZedGraph, but I didn't about R. That's why the accepted answer goes there.

I also suggest using JFreeChart for Java.

It doesn't look like there are many alternatives out there, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in **[R](http://www.r-project.org)**.  See [this R-wiki page](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-base:2yaxes) for an example.

This can also be very easy using the `doubleYScale` function, as [in these examples](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/index.php?scope=name&query=doubleYScale).

Comment: The wiki link was broken, I think I've pointed it at the correct page

Answer (score 5):

[Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/) can do this.  See the following examples:

Stacked Axis plot: [Source](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/Chaco/trunk/examples/multiaxis.py) [Screenshot of stacked axis plot http://www.enthought.com/~pwang/chaco/stacked_axes.png](http://www.enthought.com/~pwang/chaco/stacked_axes.png)

Multi-Y plot (placing multiple axes on a plot's frame): [Source](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/Chaco/trunk/examples/multiaxis.py) [Screenshot of multiple y-axis plot http://www.enthought.com/~pwang/chaco/multi-y.png](http://www.enthought.com/~pwang/chaco/multi-y.png)

Answer (score 3):

According to the GNU plot, you can have [upto 2 axii](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00068000000000000000) on GNU plot per chart.

Comment: 2 axes are not enough... the ranges of the data are normally very different and I can't group them in the same axis.

Comment: I understand, I'm just stating that it is a possiblilty to have more than one, but no more than two (unless there is a way to draw one manually that I don't know about)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure you could do this in [matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib)

Failing that there are a lot of links on that wikipedia page for other plotting libraries.

Answer (score 2):

`matlab` can do this

Comment: Yes, you can use the addaxis component from the Matlab File Exchange, but I am looking for more alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this what you want, but [ZedGraph](http://www.zedgraph.org/) supports multiple axes. it's a .net component, so you'd have to write some code to get the data in there, but it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) can plot with multiple axis (see [this sample](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_96.html#g_t2_002daxes-sample)). It is GPL (LGPL for core) library.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I was looking more for more than two axes, grouped at either the left or the right side of the plot. For instance, three axes on the left and two on the right, each with its own range and scale.

Comment: In fact, MathGL can plot several axis too. See this [sample](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_96.html#g_t2_002daxes-sample) or just execute this MGL script (by UDAV or by mgl2png,mglview and so on)

axis # first axis
xlabel 'x' 0 -1:ylabel 'y_1' 0.2 -1

yrange -2 2:origin -1.3 0 #draw other axis
axis 'y':ylabel '\colorr{y_2}' 0.2 -1

Comment: I.e., @PabloRodriguez, you can just change the axis origin (x-position). At this axis origin can be out of axis range.