# Different right and left axes in a MATLAB plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I plot a single trace in MATLAB with `plot()`. I'd like to add a right-y axis with a different set of tick marks (scaled linearly). Is this possible?

Comment: You can find many solutions on this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes

Comment: ... although, in retrospect, I'm a little hesitant to call it an *exact* duplicate. It deals with a more complicated situation, but the solutions there are still applicable (some needing a bit of modification to fit your problem).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of good suggestions on [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1719048/52738), although they deal with a more complicated situation than yours. If you want a super-simple DIY solution, you can try this:

```
plot(rand(1, 10));       % Plot some random data
ylabel(gca, 'scale 1');  % Add a label to the left y axis
set(gca, 'Box', 'off');  % Turn off the box surrounding the whole axes
axesPosition = get(gca, 'Position');           % Get the current axes position
hNewAxes = axes('Position', axesPosition, ...  % Place a new axes on top...
                'Color', 'none', ...           %   ... with no background color
                'YLim', [0 10], ...            %   ... and a different scale
                'YAxisLocation', 'right', ...  %   ... located on the right
                'XTick', [], ...               %   ... with no x tick marks
                'Box', 'off');                 %   ... and no surrounding box
ylabel(hNewAxes, 'scale 2');  % Add a label to the right y axis
```

And here's what you should get:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You may try this submission to MATLAB File Exchange - [PLOT2AXES](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7426-plot2axes).

[PLOT2AXES example http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/7426/2/plot2axes.png](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/7426/2/plot2axes.png)

Answer (score 2):

Jiro's solution is good (file Exchange function), however, it does not allow to use Matlab's built-in plot functions (bar, scatter, etc.), and you have to use plot2axes instead. Matlab's own help gives the solution to have two axes on any type of plots:
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor','k','YColor','k');

Look at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f1-11215.html

Comment: The page you're referring to doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 2):

From matlab 2016 and onwards there is an option to define on what axis one plots:

```
yyaxis left
plots...
yyaxis right
plots...
```

source:
https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html

Answer (score 1):

Open MATLAB Help with F1 and take a look at the functions below function [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) which you mentioned, there you will see [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html). This is what you probably need.

**UPDATE:** actually [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) is NOT the answer to the question as pointed by gnovice.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I find it weird that plotyy actually requires you to plot the data twice to get the desired effect.

Comment: The PLOTYY function plots *two* lines, each with their own y scale. In order to get *one line with two y scales* you'd probably have to do a couple tricky things (like plotting two lines, scaling the second one to the desired range, then making it invisible).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the following after plotting the left axis graph:

```
yyaxis right
ylabel('Right axis label')
plot(x,y1) % plot your right axis graph
```

Hope it helps.