# MATLAB: misaligned boxes in plotyy after saving as fig

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use plotyy to put two plots in one graph:

```
f = figure('Color','white');
[ax,p1,p2] = plotyy(xx, yy1, xx, yy2);
ylabel(ax(1),'Phase','FontSize',18);
ylabel(ax(2),'Spectrum','FontSize',18);
set(ax,{'ycolor'},{'k';'k'});
set(p1,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[0.4940,0.1840,0.5560]);
set(p2,'LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
xlabel(ax(1),['Frequency [THz]'],'FontSize',18);
set(ax,'FontSize',14)
```

Figure is displayed perfectly, but when I try to save it as fig something like misaligned boxes appears.

[image: incorrectly saved figure]

I tried to use linkaxes, but with no result.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, export_fig doesn't save as .fig files. Valid options there are the following: '-pdf', '-eps', '-png', '-tif', '-jpg' and '-bmp'.

Comment: What you're experiencing is unclear. Does the figure become misaligned after saving it? Or does it only come back misaligned when you load it from the `.fig` file? How are you saving the `.fig` in the first place?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour on R2012b. Seems definitely like a bug of `plotyy`: using `plotyy` and setting some axes annotations with large font size, then saving it as `.fig`, *then* reloading it, will break the alignment of the two axes implicitly involved in `plotyy`. Already `xx=linspace(-15,15,100); yy1=sin(xx); yy2=cos(xx); [ax,p1,p2] = plotyy(xx, yy1, xx, yy2); ylabel(ax(1),'Phase','FontSize',18); ylabel(ax(2),'Spectrum','FontSize',18);` will produce it when resizing the reloaded figure. Wonder if it's the same in HG2...

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am saving the figure with a simple savefig (although any other commands work the same) and it becomes misaligned after saving it to fig, because when I open it, it looks like it looks. Thanks for your help. I'll try smaller fonts then.

Comment: Reproducible in R2014a but not in R2015b. A figure saved with R2015b opens fine in R2014a as well.

Answer (score 3):

[`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) has been one of my favorite MATLAB functions to love to hate. It's a really useful function that I always seem to run into bugs with, to the point where I've completely stopped using it in favor of just stacking two (or more) axes objects and plotting to them separately. You can then set the `Position` property of the 'sub' axes to the same as your primary axes and they will stack nicely.

A functional example:

```
xx = linspace(-15,15,100);
yy1 = sin(xx);
yy2 = cos(xx);
f = figure('Color','white');

ax(1) = axes('Parent', f);
ax(2) = axes('Parent', f, 'Color', 'none', 'XTick', [], 'YAxisLocation', 'right');

p1 = plot(ax(1), xx, yy1);
hold(ax(2), 'on'); % Hold to preserve our axes properties set above
p2 = plot(ax(2), xx, yy2);
hold(ax(2), 'off');

ylabel(ax(1),'Phase','FontSize',18);
ylabel(ax(2),'Spectrum','FontSize',18);
set(ax,{'ycolor'},{'k';'k'});
set(p1,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[0.4940,0.1840,0.5560]);
set(p2,'LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
xlabel(ax(1),'Frequency [THz]','FontSize',18);
set(ax,'FontSize',14)

set(ax, 'ActivePositionProperty', 'position'); % Resize based on position rather than outerposition
set(ax(2), 'Position', get(ax(1), 'Position')); % Set last to account for any annotation changes
```

Along with stacking the axes you will also note that I have set the `ActivePositionProperty` to `position` (rather than `outerposition`). [MATLAB resizes axes automatically](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/automatic-axes-resize.html) when the `Units` property is set to `Normalized`, and it seems like this is the main spot where the issue is arising. On resizing, MATLAB also modifies the `OuterPosition` value for the second axes, causing it to resize the plot portion. The difference is small, `[0 0 1 1]` vs. `[0 0.0371 1.0000 0.9599]` in my case, but the effect is obviously very pronounced. You can use [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) to fix this, but you'll have to do it on every resize which is fairly annoying. The alternative is to resize based on the `Position`, which seems to alleviate the issue and is a tweak present in the R2015b implementation of `plotyy`. This also fixes `plotyy` except for cases where the window is very small, so I have left my answer with the more generic approach.