# How to format Matlab figures made with plotyy?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am making plot figures with Matlab and want to export them using the Presentation Export Style (File > Export Setup > Export Styles > Load settings for: "Presentation"). This usually works well enough for quick needs.

However, I am now using `plotyy` and the following problem appears. When I select the Presentation Export Style and apply it to the figure, the Y-axis labels fall out of the picture region in some cases. It seems that Matlab is not appropriately scaling everything to fit in the figure window. How can I solve this (as simple as possible)?

### Example

Here is an example with the aforementioned problem:

```
x = linspace(0,1,10);
y1 = 1000*x;
y2 = 10*x.^2;
figure; ax = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);
ylabel(ax(1),'y_1');
ylabel(ax(2),'y_2');
```

Now, if you apply the Presentation Export Style to this, you'll see what I am talking about.

I don't know if it is version specific: using 2015a right now.

Comment: [Potentially related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384294/matlab-misaligned-boxes-in-plotyy-after-saving-as-fig/34398710#34398710)

Comment: @excaza The question is different: I don't have the misaligned boxes. But your answer there seems useful for this problem as well. I'll look into it later today.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the question is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of excaza's answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384294/matlab-misaligned-boxes-in-plotyy-after-saving-as-fig), I managed to find a pretty easy solution:

Setting the `ActivePostionProperty` of the axes to `outerposition` needs to happen before formatting the figure. It will make sure that everything keeps fitting within the window. It is likely that this will misalign the two axis boxes. Then the last five lines of this working example should be executed to make them equal again AND maintain the proper fit in the figure window.

```
x = linspace(0,1,10);
y1 = 1000*x;
y2 = 10*x.^2;
figure;
ax = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);
xlabel('x')
ylabel(ax(1),'y_1');
ylabel(ax(2),'y_2');

% Set `ActivePostionProperty` to `outerposition`. This will make sure
% everything fits within the window
set(ax,'ActivePositionProperty','outerposition')

% Do some formatting......
% either with GUI or code.

% It is likely that the two axes get shifted and no longer coincide. Then
% execute this part.
p1 = get(ax(1),'Position');
p2 = get(ax(2),'Position');
p = max(p1,p2);
p(3:4) = min(p1(1:2)+p1(3:4),p2(1:2)+p2(3:4))-p(1:2);
set(ax,'Position',p);
```