# How do I plot one curve with two different units (y-axes) in the same plot window in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a curve as a function of x. The value at different x can be expressed in y1 units and well as y2 units.

I intend to plot the curve such that the left y-axis shows the value in y1 units while right y-axis of the panel shows it in the y2 units.

PS: I am trying to implement this in MATLAB.

Comment: take a look at this here http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually what the link shows is 'two' curves with two different axes. I want the 'same' curve to be represented in two different units. Hope this makes the problem clear.

Comment: I got an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676004/different-right-and-left-axes-in-a-matlab-plot

Answer (score 0):

If you need to plot the same curve with two different axis, you can use the following example

```
x=1:1000; y = sort(randn(size(x)));
figure, plotyy(x, y, x, y*100, 'plot', 'plot')
```