# plotting two axes semilog matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 2 plots with the same x data:

```
x=[0 100];
y1=x^2;
y2=e^x;
```

I want to plot y2 by **semilogy** (i.e in log scale).
How can I plot them together?
Left side - y1 Y axis;
Right side - y2 Y axis;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick Google search of the terms that you provide in your question (i.e., *'semilogy'* and *'plotting two axes matlab'*) would have shown you what I'm showing you. Anyhow...

You can use the built-in [`yyaxis` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html) to...

> Create a chart with two y-axes.

You can use the built-in [`semilogy` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html) to...

> Create a plot with a logarithmic scale for the y-axis and a linear scale for the x-axis.

Putting it all together, this is pretty much just a generalized version of the code provided in the `yyaxis` function documentation I linked above...

```
x = [ insert your x-data];
y1 = insert-your-first-func;
yyaxis left
plot(x,y1)

y2 = insert-your-second-func;
yyaxis right
semilogy(x,y2)
```

**EDIT:**
If using a Matlab version <2016a, then you won't be able to take advantage of the utility of the `yyaxis` function. In that case, there are plenty of questions on StackOverflow (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676004/different-right-and-left-axes-in-a-matlab-plot) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634426/create-an-xy-plot-with-two-y-axis)) that explain how you might go about plotting two sets of data on the same x-axis, but different y-axes (i.e., linear and semilog, for instance).

The answer is in the [`plotyy` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) too! Here it is:

> plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,'function1','function2') uses function1(X1,Y1) to plot the data for the left axis and function2(X2,Y2) to plot the data for the right axis.
>
> function can be either a function handle or a string specifying plot, semilogx, semilogy, loglog, stem, or any MATLAB® function that accepts the 
>   syntax: h = function(x,y)

The code above would now look like...

```
x = [ insert your x-data];
y1 = insert-your-first-func;
y2 = insert-your-second-func;
plotyy(x,y1,x,y2,'plot','semilogy');
```

Happy coding! Remember that Google is your friend!

Comment: That's true. If the OP is using a version of MATLAB <2016a, then `plotyy` is their best bet. There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676004/different-right-and-left-axes-in-a-matlab-plot) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634426/create-an-xy-plot-with-two-y-axis), that already explain how to use `plotyy` for this purpose.

Comment: @BillBokeey I'll mention it in my answer, just so anyone who finds this questions knows there are other options, too :)