# MATLAB: issue with putting x and y labels on each side of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

Based code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676004/different-right-and-left-axes-in-a-matlab-plot), I wrote a function which plots a figure and puts x-axis labels on both the top and bottom of the figure, as well as y-axis labels on the left and right side. My problem is that I need to run the code multiple times and each time the labels get written over, and for some reason the y-axis labels get overwritten in a weird way as shown,
first run:

[image]

second run:

[image]

The following is an mwe:

```
% sample data, plot
x=[1:168];
y=x;
plot(x, y, 'r', 'LineWidth', 1);


set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);

% set left yaxis label 
ylabel(directions{1,1},'Rotation',-360);

% Adjust position - this seems to be what's causing the issue!
ylabelh = get(gca,'YLabel');
rpos = get(ylabelh,'Position');
set(ylabelh,'Position',rpos + [1.5*rpos(1) 0 0])

% do stuff... as per link above
axesPosition = get(gca,'Position');   
hNewAxes = axes('Position',axesPosition,...  %# Place a new axes on top...
            'Color','none',...          %#   ... with no background color
            'YAxisLocation','right',...  %#   ... located on the right
            'XTick',[],'YTick',[],...           %#   ... with no x tick marks
            'Box','off');   

ylabel(hNewAxes,directions{2,1},'Rotation',-360); % yaxis label right

% Adjust position
ylabelh = get(gca,'YLabel');
Lpos = get(ylabelh,'Position');
set(gca,'YTick',[]);
set(ylabelh,'Position',Lpos+ [+Lpos(1)*0.02 0.05 0])

% -- And repeat for x axis -- %

% x axis labels
xlabel(directions{3,1},'Rotation',-360); % xaxis label bottom
% Adjust position
xlabelh = get(gca,'XLabel');
xlabpos =  get(xlabelh,'Position');
set(gca,'XTick',[]);
rpos = get(xlabelh,'Position');
% do stuff ... as above
axesPosition = get(gca,'Position');
hNewAxes = axes('Position',axesPosition,...  %# Place a new axes on top...
            'Color','none',...          %#   ... with no background color
            'XAxisLocation','top',...  %#   ... located on the right
            'XTick',[],'YTick',[], ...          %#   ... with no x tick marks
            'Box','off');   

% xaxis label top
xlabel(hNewAxes,directions{4,1},'Rotation',-360);
```

Weirdly, if I run the code as a script it's fine (well, the labels get written over but I don't see the issue with the y axis labels) but if I run as a function multiple times in debug mode (which is currently the primary way I'm using it) then I see the above artefacts.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code then check at the end you will see that you have created 3 axes in your script.  Run it once and they type `get(gcf,'Children')`.  If you run it again you are adding another 2 axes, this continues everytime you run it.

Why does this happen?

Well your code creates 2 new axes handles (which you call the same name -> which you shouldn't do) - but only after you have already used `gca` -> i.e. the current axes (if none exists one is created).

I would advise you to completly reconfigure you code.  Start by creating 2 axes before you do any plotting/labeling etc.. store the 2 axes variables independently which will allow you to refer to them as and when you need to.

Also it good practice to never rely on `gca` or `gcf` to get the currently axes or figure -> as it will eventually come back to bite you.  Store the axes/figure handles and refer to them explicitly.