# Two left Y axis

Tags: matlab, axis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes)

Dear stackoverflowers,

I need to plot 3 curves with same X axis (time) but three different dimensions (Volt, temp, current). The best outlook, to me, would be to have two Y axis on the left side, separated by a few pixel so we can read legend and ticks for each.

The answer to my questions are not [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) neither [multiple X or Y axis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f1-11215.html) . In the first case, it helps me plot two different dimensions, not three.

the latter helps me associate right or left Y axis to a particular curve. I used the YAxisLocation option for my third curve but if I put it right or left, of course it interfers with the other YAxis that was there before. There is no option like `left - 20 pixels` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Duplicate: [Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes) There are a number of viable solutions there.

Comment: Thank you gnovice ! I used a thousand of different keywords to find a solution but this one was not in the 3 first result pages I guess!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use plot (which will take care of the scale) and then include a legend to say what your units are (e.g. volts, degrees, etc)