# Two y axis with the same x-axis

Tags: matlab, axis, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes)

assuming I have the following dataset as an example here in Matlab:

```
x = linspace(0, 9, 10);
y1=arrayfun(@(x) x^2,x);
y2=arrayfun(@(x) 2*x^2,x);
y3=arrayfun(@(x) x^4,x);
```

thus you can see they have the SAME x-axis. Now I want the following plot:

one x-axis with the limits 0 to 9 (those limits should also be ticks) with N ticks (I want to be able to define N myself), thus having N-2 ticks inbetween because 0 and 9 itself are already ticks. I want y1 and y2 to refer to the same y-axis, which is being displayed on the left with ticks for 0 and max([y1, y2]) and M more ticks inbetween.
than I want to have another axis on the right, where y3 refers to...

y1, y2 and y3 should have entries in the same legend box...
thanks so far!

edit: argh just found this: [Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes) perhaps I can bould it up myself... I will try just right now!

**EDIT:** What when using logarithmic x-axis?!

Comment: For your purposes, [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks yeah, I got it to work by using this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9016-addaxis I would rather want to use plotyy but I don't see how to plot x vs y1 and y2 on the same axis and only x vs y3 on the other one!? Because plotyy only takes the arguments (x,y1,x,y2)

Comment: just FYI: Its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this documentation on [Using Multiple X- and Y-Axes](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html).  Something like this should do the trick:

```
figure
ax1 = gca;
hold on
plot(x,y1)
plot(x,y2)
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
       'XAxisLocation','top',...
       'YAxisLocation','right',...
       'Color','none',...
       'XColor','k','YColor','k');
linkaxes([ax1 ax2],'x');
hold on
plot(x,y3,'Parent',ax2);
```

Edit: whoops, missed a hold command. Should work now.  Also, to remove the second x-axis on top, simply add `'XTickLabel',[]` to the `axes` command.

As an aside, you really shouldn't use `arrayfun` for `y1=arrayfun(@(x) x^2,x);`. Instead, use the `.^` operator: `y1=x.^2;`.  It's much better style and is much quicker.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Only when I remove the last plot command I see the second axis (but than I have a second x-axis on top). When using the third plot command, the y-axis is being displayed additionally at the left.

Comment: Teaches me to post code that I didn't test.  I missed the `hold` on the second axes. I've now tested it and it works for me.

Comment: @Matt B.: I would replace all `PLOT`s with lower-level `LINE`s (that way you don't need `hold` commands), give them distinct colors, save their handles in a vector, and add a legend: `legend(hLines, 'y1','y2','y3')`

Comment: @MattB: First let me say thanks! You are right about arrayfun, it was just an quick (in this case bad) example... I'm gonna try it out!

Comment: OKay I tried it and I got it to work, even with semilogx!

Comment: +1 This is a better answer with more detail given than the accepted answer to the question this is a duplicate of.