# How to plot three curves on same plot with same X axis but different Y axes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes)

I have three vectors of data: `A`, `B`, `C`, that are function of time `t` (same t-values to 3 of them). I want to plot all three in same graph (3 different curves), but MATLAB makes them all relative to the same Y-axis, and since they are in different scales (one is from 1 to 100 and another from -5K to +5K), it minimizes the small-scale curves to nearly zero.

I just want to see how they are synchronized, but I don't care about the size relation between them. How do I do that ?

Comment: Yes... thank you for directing me there. I couldn't find it myself (blushing...)

Comment: Or use [`plotyy`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have several variables, you may to consider to scale them to some common reference, for example summing up. Like:

```
A= A/ sum(A);
B= B/ sum(B);
C= C/ sum(C);
```

or

```
A= A/ sum(abs(A));
B= B/ sum(abs(B));
C= C/ sum(abs(C));
```

or

```
A= A/ sum(A^2);
B= B/ sum(B^2);
C= C/ sum(C^2);
```

And then just plot them.