# MATLAB - Plotting multiple graphs

Tags: matlab, plot

I am new to MATLAB and am having difficulty plotting multiple graphs. Here are my vectors to graph:

```
S = [1.2421
     2.3348
     0.1326
     2.3470
     6.7389
     3.7089
     11.8534
     -1.8708
     ...]

Y = [1.1718
     1.8824
     0.3428
     2.1057
     1.6477
     2.3624
     2.1212
    -0.7971
    ...]

w = [0.1753
     0.3277]
```

`S` is my training data and `Y` is my output vector. Then I add a column vector to my training data:

```
O = ones(length(S), 1)
X = [S 0]

w = inv(X'*X)*X'*Y
```

So I am trying to plot `X`, `Y` and `w` on the same graph. I plot `w` first, hold, `X` and this is where I get lost. Basically they are not on the same scale because the size of x is much less than `X` (`X` and `Y` are both vectors of size 100 and `w` is of size 2).

```
plot(w)
```

[image: In MATLAB: result of plot(w)]

Then I do:

```
hold
plot(X)
```

[image: In MATLAB: result of hold, plot(X)]

Now the `w` that I plotted is so small compared to the plot of `X`. How would I make them the same scale? Also maybe making them a different color?

Comment: Do you need to have them in the same plot? The x- and y-scales of your two plots are very different. Maybe its better to plot them side-by-side using [subplot](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting 4 curves in a single plot, with 3 y-axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719048/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes)

Answer (score 4):

[plotyy](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) will create the figure you are looking for. See the examples in the link for further plot customization.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just comment, but I don't have enough reputation... If you are not aiming to present the data, but just be able to visualize it, you can rescale your datasets and avoid the not-so-easy-to-work-with `plotyy` (although it *is* the best answer):

```
W = W/max(W);
X = X/max(X);
plot(W)
hold on
plot(X)
```

For additional formating of the plots, see mathworks [polt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). There you can change color, linewidth and whatnot.